# Solving a*sin($\theta$) + b*cos($\theta$) - c*cos($\theta$) = d

Tags: trigonometry

Given $a, b, c, d$. How do I get the theta?

$a \cdot \sin(\theta) + b \cdot \cos(\theta) - c \cdot \cos(\theta) = d$

Comment: Is this really different from $a\sin\theta+B\cos\theta=d$, where $B=b-c$?

Comment: @egreg You are right! Why didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: Don't follow the “square” strategy; rather, set $X=\cos\theta$, $Y=\sin\theta$ and solve the system $\begin{cases}aY+BX=d\\X^2+Y^2=1\end{cases}$; alternatively, set $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ and transform the equation into $2at+B(1-t^2)=d(1+t^2)$. Squaring introduces spurious solutions and checking for them might be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is to isolate $(b-c)\cos(\theta)$ and square the equation
$$(b-c)\cos(\theta)=d-a\sin(\theta)$$ so we get
$$(b-c)^2\cos^2(\theta)=d^2+a^2\sin^2(\theta)-2ad\sin(\theta)$$
with $\cos^2(\theta)=1-\sin^2(\theta)$ you will get an quadratic equation to solve.

Comment: And so introduce spurious solutions?

Comment: So you must check your solutions!